# How to name this function

Tags: language-agnostic, naming-conventions, naming

Given this function:

```
function foo() {
    if (!doStep1) {
        return false;
    }

    if(!doStep2()) {
        return false;
    }

    ...

    // at this point, the rest can fail,
    // but the overall outcome should be considered a success

    doStep15();

    doStep16();

    ...

    return true;
}
```

I'd like to wrap everything between the two ... inside another function.

Any idea what to name this function that performs mandatory steps but whose outcome I don't care about?

Comment: I name my functions "on-the-go", I ususally don't have time to think that much of naming. Which benefits do you have from this effort?

Comment: Standard practice is to use the name `bar` once `foo` has already been used.

Comment: The function should be named according to what it actually does. The fact that it consists of a series of mandatory and then optional steps is probably an implementation detail.

Answer (score 4):

```
function mandatorySteps() {
    return doStep1() && doStep2() && ...;
}

function optionalSteps() {
    doStep15(); doStep16(); ...
}
```

Comment: That's not exactly the case. All steps are mandatory, except some trigger fail conditions, the rest (to be wrapped inside this function) do not.